# Query to get the common values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a table like

```
userId  classId 
1        1           
2        1          
3        1 
1        2 
2        2 
1        3 
2        4
3        5
```

In the above, [1, 2, 3] share class 1. [1, 2] share class 2, and so on.

If I give userId 1, 2, 3 in a query that should return classId 1.

If I give 1 and 2, the query should return 2.

If I give 1, the query should return 3.

How can I write a MySQL query for that?

Comment: Please explain how giving an input of 1 should return 3. In the other cases, you wanted to know which classes the users shared; if you only give one user, shouldn't it give all classes that user is in?

Comment: In other words you want to get the maximum ID that all of the given users have.

Comment: Sorry for making the question complicated.   Actually the table is a part of group activity.  [classId should have renamed by groupId for better readability].   What i'm trying to get is , is there any group for the given list of users.   users 1,2 and 3 form group 1,   users 1 and 2 form group 2,  we can neglect last three rows...  hope that will simplify my question.

Answer (score 1):

The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm).

Because you don't consider `class = 1` to be a valid result when given `user = {1, 2}`, you should be looking at [exact division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) (i.e. without a remainder). You also need to consider what the result should be given an empty divisor.

Answer (score 0):

This was tested with Postgresql, but I'm pretty sure it should work without much modifications under mysql.

**Table setup**

```
drop table classes;

create table classes (
    user_id     integer,
    class_id    integer
);

insert into classes values(1, 1);
insert into classes values(2, 1);
insert into classes values(3, 1);
insert into classes values(1, 2);
insert into classes values(2, 2);
insert into classes values(1, 3);
insert into classes values(2, 4);
insert into classes values(3, 5);
```

**1, 2, 3**

```
select max(class_id) from
(
  select class_id
  from classes
  where user_id = 1

  intersect

  select class_id
  from classes
  where user_id = 2

  intersect

  select class_id
  from classes
  where user_id = 3
) as foo;
```

**1, 2**

```
select max(class_id) from
(
  select class_id
  from classes
  where user_id = 1

  intersect

  select class_id
  from classes
  where user_id = 2
) as foo;
```

**1 (Could be simplified, but I prefer it so, for symmetry reasons)**

```
select max(class_id) from
(
  select class_id
  from classes
  where user_id = 1
) as foo;
```

Comment: Oups, mysql does not support "intersect" yet, but it is apparently planned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this (for users 1,2,3) -

```
SELECT t1.classId FROM (SELECT * FROM users_classes WHERE userId = 1) t1 -- for userId = 1
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM users_classes WHERE userId = 2) t2 ON t1.classId = t2.classId -- for userId = 2
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM users_classes WHERE userId = 3) t3 ON t1.classId = t3.classId -- for userId = 3
```

For users 1,2 -

```
SELECT t1.classId FROM (SELECT * FROM users_classes WHERE userId = 1) t1 -- for userId = 1
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM users_classes WHERE userId = 2) t2 ON t1.classId = t2.classId -- for userId = 2
```

These query will output all possible classId, to get one classId you can add LIMIT or aggregate function.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>     Try this
>
>
>       SELECT DISTINCT (
>         classId
>         )
>         FROM `data`
>         WHERE userid =1
>         OR userid =2 or classid = 3            
>         LIMIT 0 , 1
>
>         SELECT DISTINCT (
>         classId
>         )
>         FROM `data`
>         WHERE userid =1
>         OR userid =2            
>         LIMIT 1 , 1
>
>    SELECT DISTINCT (
>         classId
>         )
>         FROM `data`
>         WHERE userid =1     
>
>         LIMIT 2 , 1
> ```

Comment: And how does that answer the question?

Comment: Sorry....is not returning the expected answer.Actually the table is a part of group activity. [classId should have renamed by groupId for better readability]. What i'm trying to get is , is there any group for the given list of users. users 1,2 and 3 form group 1, users 1 and 2 form group 2, we can neglect last three rows... hope that will simplify my question

Comment: if u want to retrive data as per groups  then u can use groupby(groupId)... hope this helps